# NSString returning wrong count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am retrieving the SSID for my network......

```
CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
NSLog(@"Connected at:%@",myDict);
NSDictionary *myDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)myDict;
NSString *wifiName = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"SSID"];
NSLog(@"ssid is %@",wifiName);
```

wifiName is "AardVark Red Connect"

But I want to know if I'm connected to a particular network (an Internet Of Things type project and I need to connect to a specific SSID in Ad Hoc Mode to provision it)

So I strip it down with.....

```
NSArray* words = [wifiName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString* nospacestring = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Now I create a new String with what I want to be connected to.....

```
NSString *wantedNetwork = @"AardVarkRedConnect";
```

but if I do a

```
if([wantedNetwork isEqualToString:nospacestring])
{ 
     NSLog(@"Networks are the same");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"Networks are different");
}
```

I always get tripped up in the "Networks are different" side of the comparison.

If I check the length of both strings, the "nospacestring" has an extra character.  I thought maybe it was a spare \n but that wasn't the trick.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]` ?

Comment: Hadn't tried that.  I'll go home and check that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]
```

instead of

```
[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]
```